# Snap GPS coordinates to closest line, get line ID, generate and execute URL

Tags: snapping, arcgis-web-appbuilder, arcgis-portal, url, unique-id

I have a web map in Portal that has a sidewalk line layer.

Using Portal, I plan to collect sidewalk deficiencies using GPS (on a Microsoft Surface/Windows 10 device).

[image]

---

I would like to add the following functionality to the web map:

1. Using the device's current GPS coordinates, **snap** the coordinates to the closest sidewalk line.
2. Get the ID of the sidewalk line.
3. Generate a URL from the ID and the snapped coordinates.
4. Execute the URL.

   - The URL will open a work order management system **form** that is pre-populated with the sidewalk ID and the snapped coordinates.

**How can I do this in Portal?**

Comment: I'm getting the impression that this can't be done in Portal. Doing it in Collector would be an acceptable alternative.

Comment: For clarity, you aren't so much asking how you can do this in _Portal_, you're asking how can you do this inside _Web AppBuilder_ (that's your screen shot). What you want to do should be possible, but its going to be a couple hundred lines of custom JavaScript to wire up the workflow you've laid out.

Comment: Yes, this can be done. It can be done in WebApp Builder or in a stand-alone javascript API app registered with Portal. IF you have control over some of the attributes of the GPS or the ability to publish a new service, then it can be done in a single Portal query. What is the maximum distance away from your 'GPS' that you want to search for a sidewalk?